# How to make paste -d second file print down while looping?

Tags: linux, awk, files, scripting, paste

I would like to make the second file label 'b' print down the first file label 'a', like shifting down the file creating new lines I want it to print all the way down until the first line of the second file hit the last line of the first file. Would I have to put this into a file itself or could I do it from the terminal?

What it does now:

```
paste -d ' ' a b   

1  a                       
2  b                       
3  c                       
4  d                       
5  e                      
6                               
7                               
8                                 
9
```

Desired output:

```
1  ↓                          
2  a                       
3  b                       
4  c                       
5  d                       
6  e                       
7                               
8                               
9                               

1                               
2                               
3  ↓                          
4  a                      
5  b                       
6  c                       
7  d                       
8  e                       
9                                                                  

        Re-looping                   
1  b                       
2  c                       
3  d                       
4  e                             
5                               
6                               
7  ↓                          
8  List is about to loop        
9  a
```

Comment: Is the reason for doing this to create every combination of two lines from the two files?

Comment: Yes, I want the first file to be displayed all at once while the second file just goes down the list creating a new combinations. I want each line of the second file to hit every line of the first file, I updated my example.

Answer (score 0):

This post will not solve directly your problem, but will drive you to a direction close to what you are looking for.

PS: By the way, i wouldn't use `paste` for this data processing job. I would have select awk or a different - more appropriate - tool.

Anyway, with `paste` , you can consider bellow "dirty" solutions:

Case 1:

```
$ k=3
$ paste -d '  ' a <(printf ' %.0s\n' $(seq 1 $k);cat b)
1  
2  
3  
4 a
5 b
6 c
7 d
8 e
9 
#You can adjust the value of $k with a kind of loop
```

Case 2:

```
$ k=3
$ s=4
$ paste -d '  ' a <(printf ' %.0s\n' $(seq 1 $k);tail -n +$s b)
1
2
3
4 d
5 e
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: Thanks for that, could you provide an post with the awk?

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose is to create the cross product of the words in `a` with those in `b`, you may use `join` like so:

```
$ join -1 2 -2 2 a b
 1 a
 1 b
 1 c
 1 d
 1 e
 2 a
 2 b
 2 c
 2 d
 2 e
 3 a
 3 b
 3 c
 3 d
 3 e
 4 a
 4 b
 4 c
 4 d
 4 e
 5 a
 5 b
 5 c
 5 d
 5 e
 6 a
 6 b
 6 c
 6 d
 6 e
 7 a
 7 b
 7 c
 7 d
 7 e
 8 a
 8 b
 8 c
 8 d
 8 e
 9 a
 9 b
 9 c
 9 d
 9 e
```

Joining the files on a non-existing field will create all possible combinations of the lines in the two files. Note that this inserts a space at the start of each line.

Comment: Is it possible to do that without creating all possible combinations of the lines?